# Run UPDATE query while the INSERTs are running

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a DB table which size is around 100,000 rows. I Need to run an `UPDATE` query on that table (affecting every row) which runs for approximately 25 minutes. During this 25 minutes, there will be approximately 300 `INSERT`s to the same table.

I'm wondering whether those `INSERT`s will run? Will they be blocked for the time the `UPDATE` is running, and then executed, or will they just never be executed?

I'm using Postgres database.

Comment: Worth reading up on how [MVCC works](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/mvcc-intro.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, those inserts **will** run.

An UPDATE, even when changing all rows, does not block the INSERTs

Comment: Sorry, somehow I deleted too much when rewording it. The INSERTs will **not** be blocked

Answer (score 1):

If the update starts before the insert commits, then 100,000 existing records will be updated, the 300 new ones will not be.  They will not block each other, unless there is something else going on like attempts to violate a constraint or elaborate triggers.